# Instagram says link is broken during OAuth authentication

Tags: api, oauth, instagram-api

I am trying to implement OAuth authentication in instagram api but it always return with a webpage showing link is broken.

I am using following code to implement authentication

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout',300);
session_start();

//----------Instagram API Keys-----------//
define("CLIENT_ID",'7f56a1c25fea4949bb8d718809e11a88');
define("CLIENT_SECRET",'purposely hidden');  
define("REDIRECT_URI",'localhost/dp/index.php');
define("imgDir",'pics/');
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<a href="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=<?php echo CLIENT_ID;?>&redirect_uri=<?php echo REDIRECT_URI; ?>&response_type=code">Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Error which i am getting]

Comment: I don't think you can use localhost. Instagram is looking for a page that is accessible to anyone who has that URI. That being said, you will also need to update your Redirect URI on Instagram.

Comment: Thanks alot. It is working now. :D